# intersection of bounded, open, non-empty set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image: 13.9][image: 13.10]

I wonder if the theorem is still true if we change "closed" to "open". It seems that the proof will still work since none of the steps require F$_n$ to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_n=(0,\frac1{n})$ provides a counterexample for open intervals.

The fact that each $F_n$ is closed is used in the proof you posted to see that $x_0$ must be in $F_{n_0}.$

Answer (score 1):

To show $\;x_0\in F\;$ you need closedness, and for a counter example of the claim take

$$F_n=\left(0,\,\frac1n\right)\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\implies (0,1)\supset\left(0,\frac12\right)\supset\left(0,\frac13\right)\supset\ldots$$

yet

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(0,\,\frac1n\right)=\emptyset$$